# Why does Windows rename my library to the drive letter?

Tags: windows-10, libraries, drive-letter

As many others, I use custom locations for my windows libraries because my OS is on a small SSD. Downloads, Music and Pictures are all stored in folders on D:. My Video library however, has an entire disk for itself, "Video (V:)". I assigned new name and letter in disk management. As you can see (see picture), after moving the library location, the 'Videos' library loses its name and instead shows just the drive letter.

[image: picture of library named wrongly]

This problem has been following me for a few months now and it's driving me nuts. I can't find any solution. The library still exists as "Videos" in my appdata/roaming/microsoft/windows/libraries folder. Also, the Libraries (as opposed to "This PC") link looks like this (when I expand each element):
[image: picture of libraries expanded]

I have googled around but not found any answer. I have unplugged the drive, no change. The only hint I found was that Windows doesn't like entire disks as library space, but rather wants a specific folder. Creating a V:/videos/ folder results in an "invalid location" error. All drives are NTFS.

I am actually more interested in why this happens rather than fixing it (which would be nice, too). It should link to 'Libraries/Videos' but instead it's just 'V:\'.

Comment: So it didn’t rename the *library*, after all. When you expand a library, you see the actual folders included. A drive’s root folder is special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if the shell folder is redirected to the drive's root (in this case V:). Migrating it to a folder such as "V:\Videos" should not cause this problem.

If migrated to the root, Windows (File Explorer) doesn't take the desktop.ini into consideration and simply shows up the drive-letter, instead of the special folder name.

Edit:

If you can't redirect Videos to a folder (such as V:\Videos) via the Location tab, then you need to edit the registry to set the folder path manually under the [User Shell Folders](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-shell-folders-paths-defaults-restore/) key.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

Open Regedit.exe and go to the above branch.

Double-click `My Video` and set its data to `V:\Videos`

Logoff and login back for the change to take effect.

Comment: thank you for the explanation (and the edit). it's working now.